# AspectJ Interceptor not working

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, interceptor

I have created an AspectJ interceptor like

```
@Aspect
public class RequestSpecificServiceAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution( * com.mycompany.c.d.doesTreatmentEqualsAndTrigger(..))")
    private void callInterceptor(){}

    @Before("callInterceptor()")
    public void getCallStack(){
    StackTraceElement[] callingStack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    PopulateServiceDependentMap populateServiceDependentMap = new PopulateServiceDependentMap();
    populateServiceDependentMap.populateMap(callingStack, "ServiceName");
    }
}
```

This works just fine and since this was a trial code i now replaced it with the actual interceptor i wanted which is like this

```
@Pointcut("execution( * mycompany.f.g.findPluginForRequest(..)) && args(request)")
private void actualInterceptor(BSFBatchRequest request){}

@Before("actualInterceptor(request)")
public void getBSFCall(BSFBatchRequest request){ 
    StackTraceElement[] callingStack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    PopulateServiceDependentMap populateServiceDependentMap = new PopulateServiceDependentMap();
    populateServiceDependentMap.populateMap(callingStack, request);
}
```

But now my interceptor is not intercepting the call to `findPluginForRequest()` function.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

This is my spring config file(.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd"
default-autowire="no">
<context:annotation-config/>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<bean name="com.dpx.dependencyGraphFactory" class="com.mycompany.dpx.dependencytree.ModuleToModuleDependencyGraphFactory"></bean>
<bean name="com.dpx.serviceInterceptor" class="com.mycompany.dpx.dependencytree.RequestSpecificServiceAspect"/>

</beans>
```

The signature for `findPluginForRequest()` is `private AllPurposeCache<BSFBatchRequest, BSFReply> findPluginForRequest(final BSFBatchRequest request)`. I have tried changing the pointcut to

```
@Pointcut("execution(private * mycompany.f.g.findPluginForRequest(..)) && args(request)")
private void actualInterceptor(BSFBatchRequest request){}
```

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: I need more information. Please show the package name and signature of `findPluginForRequest` and also tell me if if works without the `args()` part and pointcut/advice parameters removed. Another question: In the first example you call `populateMap` with the second parameter being a string, now it is a request object. Why is that?

Comment: The package name i can't tell you cause of NDAs but i can tell you that its a normal package. Also it does not work even without the `args()` part. To answer the second question,  I call using a request object because this request object has a method which returns a string and some more data which i need. Earlier since it was a trial I just hard-coded that data and passed the string to check if it was working or not.

Comment: You want help, but are unwilling to share enough information. I asked for the signature of `findPluginForRequest`. Unless I see at least important parts of the full picture this is a quiz show with people guessing, not a meaningful question that can be answered by deduction.

Comment: the signature for `findPluginForRequest` is `private AllPurposeCache<BSFBatchRequest, BSFReply> findPluginForRequest(final BSFBatchRequest request)`. Also not very much related to this but can AspectJ interceptor cause timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer your question:

```java
private AllPurposeCache<BSFBatchRequest, BSFReply> findPluginForRequest(
  final BSFBatchRequest request
)
```

Spring AOP is not as powerful as AspectJ because it does not weave bytecode directly but is based on creating/using dynamic proxies via JDK or CGLIB. Dynamic proxies are just subclasses or classes implementing interfaces. As such they only override public methods. Your method is private, thus Spring AOP cannot intercept it. This is documented in the [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators):

> Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, protected methods are by definition not intercepted, neither for JDK proxies (where this isn’t applicable) nor for CGLIB proxies (where this is technically possible but not recommendable for AOP purposes). As a consequence, any given pointcut will be matched against public methods only!
> If your interception needs include protected/private methods or even constructors, consider the use of Spring-driven native AspectJ weaving instead of Spring’s proxy-based AOP framework. This constitutes a different mode of AOP usage with different characteristics, so be sure to make yourself familiar with weaving first before making a decision.

In order to get it working, either make the method public or switch to AspectJ.

Comment: can I use AspectJ in java directly with some changes in the xml? It would be great if i could use AspectJ just like Spring AOP.

Comment: Is it not overkill just because you do not want to expose a method? I think it is justified to make it public because you want to interact from it via AOP. Chapter 11.8 of the linked documentation explains how to configure AspectJ. RTFM, please. The decision to switch should not be taken lightly, it is really different although the syntax is the same. You seem to know so little about AOP, be careful not to shoot a mosquito with a big cannon.

Comment: It exactly as you said. I'm new to AOP and don't know much. The problem also is that the method I am trying to intercept is owned by some other team and they won't allow to make it public.

Comment: Tell them that the code is not owned by their team but by the company. If it is your job to implement a cross-cutting concern touching on their code, they ought to change it. Alternatively, you need to find another place to hook into. Let us stop the discussion here, this is not technical anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It looks good to me, though i am not sure did you miss `@Aspect`. Another way of doing it where you can combine pointcut and advice at single place . To avoid any mistake in package name i am replacing `e.f.g.findPluginForRequest` with `findPluginForRequest`. You can put it back once you are sure there is nothing wrong in package name

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("execution(* findPluginForRequest(..))&& args(request)")
    public void beforeeAdvice(BSFBatchRequest request ){

    }

}
```

Comment: This code is within a class with the `@Aspect` annotation so no problem there. I shall try to combine it and let you know.